# How do I fetch Weather's API 'forecastday' using axios?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, discord.js, weather-api

I use WeatherAPI's service, which returns the weather forecast given the city name
The URL looks like this `https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=[API_KEY]&q=tokyo&aqi=no`

After trying to paste that URL into my browser and pasting the result into a JSON beautifier, here's the result

[image: Result]

Here's the weird part. I tried using axios to fetch the information from my app and printing it out, this is what it gave me

[image: Result]

It was unable to fetch `forecastday` and instead gave me a `[Object]`, which didn't make any sense to me since it worked just fine on my browser

Here's my code (sorry for the spaghetti formatting)
https://pastebin.com/9eJQy5Bf

I tried reinstalling the library, using proxies but the result remained the same.

Comment: where's your code?

Comment: Your data is fetched, it is just not logged, try accessing a single property or stringifying, `console.log(res.data.forecast.forecastday[0].day)` or `console.log(JSON.stringify(res.data))`

Comment: @axtck That didn't work ([Output](https://imgur.com/a/xNxxqbE)). It wasn't able to recognize anything inside `forecastday` and mark them as `undefined`

Comment: @axtck I tried separating the variables and printing them out, and just like you said, the information was fetched [code](https://imgur.com/a/Gk1bFOv) [console](https://imgur.com/a/VDxfrMG). However, trying to access any information inside that variable would still return `undefined` [console](https://imgur.com/a/g2e949L). There's a `date` variable in the response, as you can see in [this image](https://imgur.com/a/JiZMOhY)

Comment: Hi @sonntt did you figure it out? Anything I can help you with

Comment: @axtc Thanks for pointing out my mistake, I just solved that problem :)
Still, why does javascript represent the whole array as `[Object]`? Was it because it was too long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`forecast.forecastday` is an object array, to access a property from a particular object, you have to specify the index of the object in the array.

For example if you want the `date` property of the first object.

```js
const data = {
  forecast: {
    forecastday: [{
      date: "2022-04-03"
    }]
  }
}

const date = data.forecast.forecastday[0].date; // index [0] = first element

console.log(date);
```

If you would have multiple days, you could loop over them or use a function like `map()` to get the specific items.

```js
const data = {
  forecast: {
    forecastday: [{
        date: "2022-04-03",
        date_epoch: 123456789
      },
      {
        date: "2022-04-04",
        date_epoch: 123456789
      }
    ]
  }
}

const dates = data.forecast.forecastday.map(({ date }) => {
  return { date }
});

console.log(dates);
```